# Getting error map of Topo To Raster interpolation in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, arcgis-9.3, anudem

I have about 10 point shapefiles containing a lot of points each. I would prefer not to join them into one shapefile.

I am using interpolation method Topo to Raster to create a DTM. This method can deal with many separate datasets. I'm using ArcMap 9.3 (and have access to 10).

I would like to get errors of the estimates, to check if they have normal distribution.

How can I get the interpolation errors?

Like the [-e flag option in GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.surf.idw.html).

Is it available only for kriging?

Is it the only way, to compute them manually comparing each dataset to the resulting raster?

Comment: Although kriging produces a so-called "error map," it is not what it sounds like. To help you appreciate what it is *not*, I will just remark that once you have specified a variogram model, *you can produce that error map with absolutely no data at all.* In geostatistics, the errors you are looking for are estimated through conditional simulation. You can do almost the same thing, although it will be painful: you systematically leave out one point from the dataset, recreate the DTM (at least in the neighborhood of the left-out point), and measure its error there. Repeat for all points.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the clarification. So what I need is not geostatistical error map, but difference between points and the overlaying cells (the interpolation is not exact).

Comment: Almost: even when the interpolation is inexact, measuring those differences usually grossly underestimates the errors. To be honest about it, you need to remove some of your data, re-interpolate using the rest, and see how well you did by comparison to the data that had been held out. By doing this many times in a controlled way you can estimate how large the likely errors are when you use all the data. Variants of this are called the "jackknife" (which often is used to cross-validate variogram models for kriging) and, more generally, "bootstrapping."

Comment: I'm confused. How do you estimate the error at a point where you don't have the correct value? I don't see how dropping points solves this problem. For the sake of discussion, let's treat this as a 1D problem. Let's say I have data at twice the raster spacing with values 0,1,0,1,0,1,... Linearly interpolating, I'll get .5 at the missing points. Now let's say I drop one of my points, one of the 1s. If I interpolate over this missing point I'll get 0 for the three values between the two 0s, and by the suggestion, I'll estimate my error a 1 at my known point. But that's meaningless as I see it

Comment: @Llaves, If a given point has undue influence, to the degree that you are implying, then the assumption of stationarity is not being met. Bootstrap/Jackknife approaches are common and well represented in the literature. A Jackknife holds back a single observation from your model but iterates through all or n-percent of the observations thus, requires n models. You cannot hold all of your data because, even with inexact interpolators, your smoothest error will be around your points. This will provide a bias in the error distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep in mind that the topo to raster tool is an implementation of the Hutchinson ANUDEM model. This is a conditional spline model and as such, enforces certain conditions in relation to sinks, drainage, etc... It is also a best approximation based on an iterative  multi-scale spline fit. Because of this, estimated elevation may deviate from the observed data and, according to the model, not be an error per se. I am not sure that an error assessment such as RMSE is appropriate in this regard. You could plausibly receive a RMSE that does not represent the quality DEM.

The authors of ANUDEM recommended some [qualitative assessment](http://fennerschool.anu.edu.au/research/products/anudem-vrsn-53#acton-tabs-link--tabs-fenner_product_tabs-middle-3) of correctness but there is nothing akin to a variance surface like what is produced in a Kriging model.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary kriging provides a standard error map that shows the uncertainty related to the predicted values.
Steps:

Right-click the geostatistical layer in the ArcMap table of contents that was created using ordinary kriging and click Change output to Prediction Standard Error.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but I am not using kriging and not working with geostatistical layers. Topo to Raster is a completely different method.